# woo commerce city based shipping

Tags: wordpress

I'm new in wordpress and currently building a Online Shop and I use woo commerce plugin. My question is about shipping. What I want is that the shipping is available only in Philippines and the shipping cost is based on city. Fixed shipping for each city. Quantity and total order is not important here.
I hope someone can help me.

any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: go to admin panel > woocommerce > setting > shipping . can you see some options there ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this extension of WooThemes can help you. It costs a bit but will help you with your problem.

[Table Rate Shipping](http://www.woothemes.com/products/table-rate-shipping-2/)